# GSON get key from JsonPrimitive in deserilizer

Tags: java, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a Json object that I'm transforming into an object that has a 3 date members. I want to get the key during the deserialization process but it seem that Gson treat the Date.class as a JsonPrmitive. Which stops me from getting the key.

Is there any other way to get the key?

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        System.out.println("json.isJsonPrimitive() = " + json.isJsonPrimitive());
        System.out.println("json.isJsonNull() = " + json.isJsonNull());
        System.out.println("json.isJsonArray() = " + json.isJsonArray());
        System.out.println("json.isJsonObject() = " + json.isJsonObject());

        try {
            return Date.from(Instant.parse(json.getString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("blah date, change it: " + json.getString());
        }

    }

}
```

json example of the body would look like this:

```
{
    "name": "potato",
    "dateCreated": "Mon Feb 10 08:55:17 EST 2019"
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with json snippet

Comment: @Smile .... I added a json example

Comment: I think you're missing something with your "primitives can't have keys". That's perfectly true but that doesn't matter : what you need is the key that holds the primitive in the container object.

Comment: You'd have the same problem handling objects. Let's say I have `{ "a" : { "b" : "foo"}}` as global input and I'm currently handling the inner object `{ "b" : "foo" }`; I can access its keys (`["b"]`) but that won't tell me which key of the outer object it was associated with (`a`), because that's a property of that object and not of the inner object I'm currently handling

Comment: @Aaron ... I understand that... that is why I'm asking if there is a way around it to get the key without nesting it inside the parent key like this `{"dateCreated": {"dateCreated" : "Mon Feb 10 08:55:17 EST 2019"}}`

Comment: Your problem is that a `JsonDeserializer<Date>` doesn't deserialize an object that contains a date, it deserializes a date : it's called with only `"Mon Feb 10 08:55:17 EST 2019"` rather than with `{"name": "potato", "dateCreated": "Mon Feb 10 08:55:17 EST 2019"}` and therefore won't have access to the associated key.

Comment: Yes, that is the point of the question. I'm trying to find another way around that if possible.